# Theorem 3.6-5 Kreyszig: surjectivity

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-explanation

[image]
[image]

[image]

I can't understand the last part of this theorem, that is the part where he proves that T is surjective.
Could someone explain the details to me? The first thing I don't understand is why a generic $\tilde{x}$ in $\tilde{H}$ can be written by that sum.

Comment: The first thing you must understand is the definition of [Hilbert dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space#Hilbert_dimension). For this, review the definition and properties of [Hilbert basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space#Orthonormal_bases).

Comment: @AnneBauval Thanks! but where is the fact written that every element of a Hilbert space can be written as a series?

Comment: In a [subparagraph of the second link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space#Bessel's_inequality_and_Parseval's_formula).

Comment: Yes, but the coefficient are the Fourier coefficient, while in the proof we have $\alpha_k$

Comment: Fourier is off topic here. Again, review the definition and properties of Hilbert basis. $x=\sum\alpha_k e_k$ iff $\forall k,\alpha_k=\langle x,e_k\rangle.$